# How to safely convert time to unix timestamp in Java?

Tags: java

It seems the following doesn't work properly. For example for value "2014-04-10 12:58:23.0" and "2014-04-10 00:58:23.0", it yields same answer.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Long timestamp = dateFormat.parse(date).getTime()/1000L;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your input strings are in 24-hour time format while your format string specifies 12-hour time. Try using `H` instead of `h`.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. interesting, as it works with 14:00 etc, so the only problematic hour is 12:00 - 13:00

Comment: No, all the hours are problematic I think. I haven't checked this, but I think the only reason it *seems* to work is because Calendar, and therefore SimpleDateFormat, is *lenient* (check the docs) by default, which means it will try its best to parse invalid input. You might want to turn that off after you fix your pattern.